# Arduino weather vane

Tags: sensors

My little weather station is run on a Nano and has the anemometer and the temp/humidity sensor.  A smoke detector is on the way because I live where wildfire is a big concern.

I would like to build a simple weather vane without spending a lot to buy the commercial solutions.  Rotary potentiometers have dead spots and using a bunch of hall effect sensors would use up too many digital inputs to be useful, afaik.

Question:  How can I build a simple direction sensor?

Comment: There are two-axis analog hall sensors that detect the orientation of a magnet, but they cost a bit more.  You could probably make yourself a low resolution absolute optical encoder with hand tools or a 3d printer.

Comment: Use two pots with the dead-spots at opposite ends.

Comment: Not sure but I think you should be able to use a magnetometer (compass). 5US on Amazon.com could afford you something good enough. https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-HMC5883L-Electronic-Compass-Magnetic/dp/B00UAIY698/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1477482294&sr=8-2&keywords=gy+271

Comment: Thank you for your pointer.  Here is the one I just ordered:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SDTFI1Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with 4 reed sensors.  With experimentation I found I can successfully detect 8 distinct directions using 4 reed switches since the rare-earth magnet will switch two on at once when it is in between.

Thank you all for your answers.  Upvotes for everyone for the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Its a long time since I looked at this and the details are a bit misty, so sorry for the inaccuracies, but I'm sure people will correct them for me :)

I originally brought one of these http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-replacement-wind-direction-sensor-for-n96fyn96gy-n81nf and then decided to take it to bits, like you do.

The vane spins a magnet around and this triggers 1 of 8 reed switches as it passes around.  The read switch is connected to VCC and a resistor and the resistors feed into a common wire back to the microprocessor.  The 8 resistors all have different values, so the result is a differing output voltage depending on which reed switch has been triggered.

So what you need is:

- A magnet
- A number of read switches positioned far enough apart so only one is triggered at a time
- A number of different resistors

Supply 5V from you Nano and read the result on an analogue pin, then come up with a calibration table to work out the direction.

I hope that makes sense.
(Sorry I can't draw you a circuit diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Another option (similar to reed switches) is to do it optically.

The vane is on an axle. The axle has a disc attached to it. The disc has a small notch out of the edge.

Positioned around the edge are a whole series of photo-interrupters. The disc spins between the infra-red beams and the notch allows only one of them to pass light at a time.

Make the notch the right size so that as one interrupter turns off the next one turns on - you need one on all the time. You could over-compensate slightly so that on occasion two adjacent interrupters are on at once, in which case you can say it's between the two.

A similar system is to use a disc with a series of special slots cut in it (see [Gray Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)) which allow light to pass through onto a line of photodiodes. In different rotations different combinations of photodiodes are on, and that gives you your direction.

Comment: The Arduino has plenty of pins (unless you're using lots and lots of them already). Think KEYPAD.